# C++ winsock server accept function returns 10022 error

Tags: c++, codeblocks, winsock

I got rid of the error, now I seem to be stuck on something else.

I have separate Winsock client and server programs on Code::Blocks. I'm trying to send a message from the client to the server, but the server program seems to freeze before the accept() function, doing nothing beyond the "Listening for incoming connections." output. The message in the client buffer never shows up in the server console.

It definitely looks like there's something going on with the accept function in the server program. That seems to be where the server program freezes. I tried to type a random cout line after that and there was no output for it.

The client seems to freeze, too, after "Message Sent." But then after a few minutes I get "recv failed" then "Reply Received" and then a line of what seems like emoticons. I think I have the image linked below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVPyJ.jpg)

Here's my client code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET sock;
    sockaddr_in server;
    char *buffer, server_reply[2000];
    int recv_size;

    int iResult;

iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
} else {
     printf("WSAStartup successful!: %d\n", iResult);
}

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET){
    printf("Socket not created.\n");
} else {
    printf("Socket created.\n");
}

    server.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(80);

    if(connect(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&server, sizeof(server)) != 0){
        printf("Connect Error : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    } else {
        printf("Connected\n");
    };

    buffer = "Hello there!";
    send(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

        printf("Message Sent.\n");


    if((recv_size = recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
    }

    puts("Reply received\n");
    //Add a NULL terminating character to make it a proper string before printing
    server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
    puts(server_reply);


    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Here's my server code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET server1, client;
    sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;


    int iResult;

iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
} else {
     printf("WSAStartup successful!: %d\n", iResult);
}

server1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (server1 == INVALID_SOCKET){
    printf("Socket not created.\n");
} else {
    printf("Socket created.\n");
}

    serverAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(8888);

    if(bind(server1, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        printf("Bind failed. : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    } else {
        printf("Bind successful.\n");
    }

    if(listen(server1, SOMAXCONN) != 0){
        printf("Server not listening. : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    } else {
        cout << "Listening for incoming connections..." << endl;
    }



    char buffer[1024];
    int clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
    if((client = accept(server1, (SOCKADDR *)&clientAddr, &clientAddrSize)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Connect Error : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    } else {
        cout << "Client connected!" << endl;
        recv(client, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        cout << "Client says: " << buffer << endl;
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

        closesocket(client);
        closesocket(server1);
        cout << "Client disconnected." << endl;
    }
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to build a Winsock server program to use with my client program using C++ in CodeBlocks. However, the accept function returns error code 10022, which from what I've read means invalid argument. I don't see how any of my arguments in the accept function are invalid. Thanks for any help!

```
int main()
{

    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET server1, client;
    sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;


    int iResult;

iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
} else {
     printf("WSAStartup successful!: %d\n", iResult);
}

server1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (server1 == INVALID_SOCKET){
    printf("Socket not created.\n");
} else {
    printf("Socket created.\n");
}

    serverAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(INADDR_ANY);
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(8888);

    bind(server1, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    listen(server1, SOMAXCONN);

    cout << "Listening for incoming connections..." << endl;

    char *buffer;
    int clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
    if((client = accept(server1, (SOCKADDR *)&clientAddr, &clientAddrSize)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Connect Error : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    } else {
        cout << "Client connected!" << endl;
        recv(client, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        cout << "Client says: " << buffer << endl;
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

        closesocket(client);
        closesocket(server1);
        cout << "Client disconnected." << endl;
    }
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did `bind` and `listen` succeed? Have the program check the error codes from both and report and handle failure. Hard to tell if something's wrong if you don't check.

Comment: You are passing interger value to function which takes `const char*` - `inet_addr(INADDR_ANY);` should be replaced by `htonl(INADDR_ANY);`.

Answer (score 2):

10022 is `WSAEINVAL`.  Per the [`accept()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-accept) documentation:

> WSAEINVAL
>   The `listen` function was not invoked prior to `accept`.

The [Windows Socket Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinSock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) documentation also says:

> WSAEINVAL
>   10022
>
> Invalid argument.
>
> Some invalid argument was supplied (for example, specifying an invalid level to the `setsockopt` function). In some instances, it also refers to the current state of the socket—for instance, **calling `accept` on a socket that is not listening**.

OK, so lets look at your `listen()` call:

```
listen(server1, SOMAXCONN);
```

Nothing out of the ordinary there, assuming `server1` is a valid socket (which you do check for, but you don't stop your program if `socket()` failed).

You are not checking for any `listen()` errors.  Per the [`listen()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-listen) documentation, one of the possible errors is:

> WSAEINVAL
>   The socket has not been bound with `bind`.

OK, so lets look at your `bind()` call next:

```
bind(server1, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
```

Again, you are not checking for any `bind()` errors.  Per the [`bind()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-bind) documentation, one of the possible errors is:

> WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL
>   The requested address is not valid in its context.
>
> This error is returned if the specified address pointed to by the name parameter is not a valid local IP address on this computer.

Which you are likely to get, because you are not populating `serverAddr` correctly, specifically on this line:

```
serverAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(INADDR_ANY);
```

`INADDR_ANY`is defined as `0`, so you are setting the `S_addr` field to the result of `inet_addr(0)`, which is not valid so `INADDR_NONE` (0xFFFFFFFF) is returned, which again, you are not checking for. The correct assignment is to use `INADDR_ANY` as-is instead:

```
serverAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

So, to wrap up, your error handling is inadequate, allowing errors to accumulate until you finally decide to do for errors all the way on `accept()`, which is way too late.  You need to check EVERY function result for failure along the way, and STOP when you do encounter an error.

Answer (score 1):

`inet_addr` takes `const char*` which represents IPv4 address in numbers and dots notation. You are passing `INADDR_ANY` to this function, it compiles but doesn't work as expected because `INADDR_ANY` equals 0, so `inet_addr` is called with null pointer. You should check the return code of this function, -1 indicates the error. And I assume you got it.

If you want to bind any local address you should use `INADDR_ANY` with `htonl`:

```
serverAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

---

This

```
char *buffer;
recv(client, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
```

leads to undefined behaviour. buffer is uninitialized. This call of `recv` wants to read 4/8 bytes - `sizeof(buffer)`, and write into uninitialized *buffer* pointer. You need to create a buffer with some initial size, for example by calling malloc/calloc:

```
char * buffer = malloc(10);
recv(client,buffer,10,0);
// free buffer after data was read
```

Comment: I'll gleefully trade a `std::vector` for that `malloc` if permitted by the program requirements.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, of course you are right, it is tagged with C++ so `std::vector` might be used here. My intention was to indicate the problem with allocated buffer. For me the sequence of following functions `bind,listen,recv` is always associated  with C language - clumpy and painful, so my first idea was to use `malloc`. I would propose vector if OP used e.g. boost::asio api :)

Comment: I would just use a fixed array instead: `char buffer[10];` or `std::array<char, 10> buffer;` then `sizeof(buffer)` will work

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line from your code:

```
using namespace std;
```

And every thing will work fine.

This error is caused because std package have a similar bind function so when you call bind it calls std::bind instead of the bind for the socket.